# Subquery returned more than 1 value. not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to update record in a table using sub query but I am not able to do it.

update Employee set Slug= (
       select                                   SUBSTRING(Icc.Name,CHARINDEX(',',Icc.Name+1,len(Name))
            from Category C, Import_Category Icc
          where c.Name like Icc.Name)

Category and Import Category tables has Name column. What I am doing wrong ? Please help me.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* You mean beside not reading the words in the message, which tell you **exactly** what you're doing wrong? *Subquery returned more than 1 value* is extremely clear in meaning. Your subquery returned more than 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is self explanatory. Your sub query is returning moer than one element. You have to ensure your sub select only returns 1 row.

Use for example:

```
update Employee
set Slug= (
  select top 1 SUBSTRING(Icc.Name,CHARINDEX(',',Icc.Name+1,len(Name))
  from Category C, Import_Category Icc
  where c.Name like Icc.Name)
```

Comment: This will work syntactically, but `TOP 1` will not guarantee that the *correct* row is used. To sort that out, we would need more info concerning the purpose of the query.

Comment: Exactly, I put an example in purpose to make the point. He will definitely have to adjust regarding his business needs, as they are not expressed in his question